# How to parse custom tags using nltk.Regexp.parser()

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nltk

My question is similar to this unanswered question: [Using custom POS tags for NLTK chunking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744659/using-custom-pos-tags-for-nltk-chunking), but the error I am getting is different. I am trying to parse a sentence to which I have added my own domain specific tags.

For example:

```
(u'greatest', 'P'), (u'internet', 'NN'), (u'ever', 'A'), 
(u',', ','), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'its', 'PRP$'), (u'being', 'VBG'), 
(u'slow', 'N'), (u'as', 'IN'), (u'hell', 'NN')`
```

where `(u'slow', 'N')` is a custom tag `'N'`.

I am trying to parse this using the following:

```
grammar=r"""
Chunk:`{<A>?*<P>+}`
"""
parser=nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Illegal chunk pattern: `{<A>?*<P>+}`
```

Does `nltk.RegexpParser` process custom tags? Is there any other nltk or python based parser which can do that?

Comment: The grammar is not showing up in the block code: it is `grammar=r"""
Chunk:{<A>?*<P>+}
"""`

Comment: You need to pass the grammar as a string, not as a regular expression.

Comment: @louism: No thats not a necessity. The grammar can be passed as a string. Refer http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nltk.RegexpParser **can** process custom tags.

Here is how you can modify your code to work:

```
# Import the RegexpParser
from nltk.chunk import RegexpParser

# Define your custom tagged data. 
tags = [(u'greatest', 'P'), (u'internet', 'NN'), (u'ever', 'A'), 
(u',', ','), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'its', 'PRP$'), (u'being', 'VBG'), 
(u'slow', 'N'), (u'as', 'IN'), (u'hell', 'NN')]

# Define your custom grammar (modified to be a valid regex).
grammar = """ CHUNK: {<A>*<P>+} """

# Create an instance of your custom parser.
custom_tag_parser = RegexpParser(grammar)

# Parse!
custom_tag_parser.parse(tags)
```

This is the result you would get for your test data:

```
Tree('S', [Tree('CHUNK', [(u'greatest', 'P')]), (u'internet', 'NN'), (u'ever', 'A'), (u',', ','), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'its', 'PRP$'), (u'being', 'VBG'), (u'slow', 'N'), (u'as', 'IN'), (u'hell', 'NN')])
```

Comment: Hi. Yes I realized that it can process custom tags and there was an error in the way I had written the regular expression for the grammar. 
Thanks for the detailed answer in any case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with NTLK, but in Python regular expressions `?*` is a syntax error.  Perhaps you meant `*?` which is a lazy quantifier.