# checking action in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

now that i've determined what the subject, action and location/time are using this code:

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk

text = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
words = text.split()
sent = [w for w in words if not w == 'computer']
sentence = pos_tag(sent)

grammar = '''
Action: {<NN.*>?<VB.*><RB.*>?}
Location/Time: {<IN><NN.*>+}
Subject: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN.*>}
'''
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar, "Input")
result = cp.parse(sentence)

subjects = []
actions = []
locations_times = []

for word in result:
    if isinstance(word, nltk.tree.Tree):
        if word.label() == 'Subject':
            subjects.append(word)

for word in result:
    if isinstance(word, nltk.tree.Tree):
        if word.label() == 'Action':
            actions.append(word)

for word in result:
    if isinstance(word, nltk.tree.Tree):
        if word.label() == 'Location/Time':
            locations_times.append(word)
```

How can i check if the action == 'whatever' do something, else do something else.

ive tried this when typing "what time is it" as the input but it always prints failure:

```
if actions[0] == '(Action time/NN is/VBZ)':
    print('success')
else:
    print('failure')
```

please help

Comment: What are you inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The result from a parser will be at least one `Tree` object, which you will have to recursively evaluate. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975573/how-to-parse-custom-tags-using-nltk-regexp-parser) for an example of using a parser and the result it returns.